# NodeJs/MongoDB - lookup function doesnt return results as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I have two defined two schemas with are filled with data.

// Schema 1

```
const geoSchema = new Schema({
  ip: String,
  lat: String,
  lon: String,
});

const GeoModel = mongoose.model("geo", geoSchema);
```

// Schema 2

```
const ipAddressSchema = new Schema({
  ip: String,
  comment: String,
  mbps: Number,
  pps: Number,
});

const IpAddressModel = mongoose.model("ip-address", ipAddressSchema);
```

I try to join these two schemas using lookup function through the same filed name, **ip** specifically.

```
 const result = await IpAddressModel.aggregate()
    .lookup({
      from: "geo",
      localField: "ip",
      foreignField: "ip",
      as: "geo",
    })
    .exec();
```

In results i get ip addresses, but the **geo** field is empty.

```
{
    "_id": "63fdd490533255bcdbe14683",
    "ip": "172.17.32.19",
    "comment": "",
    "mbps": 1918,
    "pps": 28844,
    "__v": 0,
    "geo": []
}
```

Comment: There might not be any ip that can be mapped, are you sure both collections have same ip ?

Comment: If there are multiple results, check them by unwind them to see how many documents ave geo after lookup

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 db.ipAddressSchema.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "geoSchema",
          localField: "ip",
          foreignField: "ip",
          as: "geo"
        }
      }
    ])
```

[Playground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jRGUH0eVNKv)

Answer (score 0):

```
    const geoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ip: String,
        lat: String,
        lon: String,
    });

    const ipAddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ip: String,
        comment: String,
        mbps: Number,
        pps: Number,
    });


    const GeoModel = mongoose.model('geoSchema', geoSchema);
    const IpAddressModel = mongoose.model('ipAddressSchema', ipAddressSchema);


   IpAddressModel.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "geoSchema",
          localField: "ip",
          foreignField: "ip",
          as: "geo"
        }
      }
    ]).exec((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
```